# Where can I find word-for-word translation for "Beijing Huan Ying Ni" song?

Tags: translation, learning, songs

I'm trying to learn Chinese by listening to music, and I've been listening to the Olympic song "Beijing Huan Ying Ni." But I don't know what the words mean. All the translations online are approximate translations that don't actually translate word for word. Does anyone know where I can find a word for word translation by chance?

(This is the best I can do in Chinese: Wǒ xiǎng xué pǔtōnghuà, suǒyǐ wǒ tīng "Běijīng huānyíng nǐ." Kěshì wǒ bù zhīdào zì shénme yìsi. Word for word translation zài nǎr?)

Comment: What you have shown is 'character by character pinyin'

Comment: I see you believe in diving into the deep end? Your ambition is certainly admirable. Wish you all the best.  千里之行，始於足下; -- Qiānlǐ zhī xíng, shǐyú zú xià; (The commonly used translation is "A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step') Looks like your "single step" is a rather huge one.

Comment: I'm also learning with language tapes :)

Comment: [Simialr](https://chinesepandamusic.wordpress.com/) but seems only it share's song.

Comment: Tang Ho --- that was me asking this question in pinyin, not me translating the song. Not sure what you mean. I know I'm using pinyin.

Answer (score 2):

Original post is [here](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/62002170.html), also check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTeGoUUt0l0).

接另一个晨曦 带来全新空气

气息改变情味不变 茶香飘满情谊

我家大门常打开 开放怀抱等你

拥抱过就有了默契 你会爱上这里

不管远近都是客人请不用客气

相约好了在一起 我们欢迎你

Dawning of another morning filled with refreshing air

The air has changed; but emotion scents like green tea

My doors are always open, ready to embrace you with a hug

A hug to know you better, you'll love this place

Wherever you're from you'll be our guest so just be at home

We have agreed to meet here, we'd like to welcome you.

我家种著万年青 开放每段传奇

为传统的土壤播种 为你留下回忆

陌生熟悉都是客人请不用拘礼

第几次来没关系 有太多话题

The Everygreen at my place is quite legendary

Sown on the old Soil to record your memory

Strangers, old pals are our guests, so just be at home

Whether you're newcomers or revisitors, we've lots to chat

北京欢迎你 为你开天辟地

流动中的魅力充满著朝气

北京欢迎你 在太阳下分享呼吸

在黄土地刷新成绩

Welcome to Beijing, we built these all for you

The charm is flowing, fresh spirit's everywhere.

Welcome to Beijing, have some fresh air under the sun

Let's set our new records on this Soil

我家大门常打开 开怀容纳天地

岁月绽放青春笑容 迎接这个日期

天大地大都是朋友请不用客气

画意诗情带笑意 只为等待你

My doors are always open, we've space for the world

Time flies with youthful smiles, we all wait for this day

Under the sky, everyone be our guest, so just be at home

Nice scenary with smiling faces, all awaiting there for you

北京欢迎你 像音乐感动你

让我们都加油去超越自己

北京欢迎你 有梦想谁都了不起

有勇气就会有奇迹

Welcome to Beijing, we're reaching you like this melody

Let's excel and try our best

Welcome to Beijing, dreamers are forerunners

Miracles are for those daring to try.

北京欢迎你 为你开天辟地

流动中的魅力充满著朝气

北京欢迎你 在太阳下分享呼吸

在黄土地刷新成绩

Welcome to Beijing, we built these all for you

The charm is flowing, fresh spirit's everywhere.

Welcome to Beijing, have some fresh air under the sun

Let's set our new records on this Soil

北京欢迎你 像音乐感动你

让我们都加油去超越自己

北京欢迎你 有梦想谁都了不起

有勇气就会有奇迹

Welcome to Beijing, we're reaching you like this melody

Let's excel and try our best

Welcome to Beijing, dreamers are forerunners

Miracles are for those daring to try.

------- 京戏 -------

我家大门常打开 开放怀抱等你

拥抱过就有了默契 你会爱上这里

不管远近都是客人请不用客气

相约好了在一起 我们欢迎你

My doors are always open, ready to embrace you with a hug

A hug to know you better, you'll love this place

Wherever you're from you'll be our guest so just be at home

We have agreed to meet here, we'd like to welcome you.

北京欢迎你 为你开天辟地

流动中的魅力充满著朝气

北京欢迎你 在太阳下分享呼吸

在黄土地刷新成绩

Welcome to Beijing, we built these all for you

The charm is flowing, fresh spirit's everywhere.

Welcome to Beijing, have some fresh air under the sun

Let's set our new records on this Soil

我家大门常打开 开怀容纳天地

岁月绽放青春笑容 迎接这个日期

天大地大都是朋友请不用客气

画意诗情带笑意 只为等待你

My doors are always open, we've space for the universe

Time flies with youthful smiles, we all wait for this day

Under the sky, everyone's our guest, so just be at home

Nice scenary with smiling faces, all awaiting there for you

北京欢迎你 像音乐感动你

让我们都加油去超越自己

北京欢迎你 有梦想谁都了不起

有勇气就会有奇迹

Welcome to Beijing, we're reaching you like this melody

Let's try to excel ourselves

Welcome to Beijing, dreamers are forerunners.

Miracles are for those daring to try.

北京欢迎你 为你开天辟地

流动中的魅力充满著朝气

北京欢迎你 在太阳下分享呼吸

在黄土地刷新成绩

Welcome to Beijing, we built these all for you

The charm is flowing, fresh spirit's everywhere.

Welcome to Beijing, have some fresh air under the sun

Let set our new records on this Soil

北京欢迎你 像音乐感动你

让我们都加油去超越自己

北京欢迎你 有梦想谁都了不起

有勇气就会有奇迹

Welcome to Beijing, we're reaching you like this melody

Let's try to excel ourselves

Welcome to Beijing, dreamers are forerunners.

Miracles are for those daring to try.

北京欢迎你 有梦想谁都了不起

有勇气就会有奇迹

北京欢迎你 有梦想谁都了不起

有勇气就会有奇迹

Welcome to Beijing, dreamers are forerunners.

Miracle is for those daring to try.

Welcome to Beijing, dreamers are forerunners.

Miracles are for those daring to try.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm hoping to find something word for word? For example, "qing bu yong ke qi" doesn't really translate to "so just be at home" right? It's more like "please don't guest air" or something? It might not exist anywhere lol.

Comment: I recommend google translate for 'word by word' translation.

Comment: Hm. I'm trying to translate: 有  梦   想    谁   都  了   不 起 / yǒu mèng xiǎng shuí dōu liǎo bù qǐ into English. Google gives me: have/ dream/ who/ all/ not/ air. The lyrics are "dreams are the forerunners." I still don't know what this line means.

Comment: Try 'word by word', 有 梦 想 - have dream,  谁 都 - anyone, 了 不 起 - amazing. It's different from the lyrics, since lyrics is not a direct translation, but just translated the idea.

Comment: Very often a 'word by word' translation from one language to another would give you something garbled and even an unintended hilarious rendition. As for 有 梦 想 谁 都 了 不 起, one way to translate the intended idea "poetically" is -- Every Dreamer is an Achiever.

Comment: The problem is not with 有 梦 想 谁 都..., (which simply means, "Anyone with dreams / ambition...), but 了 不 起 which could be translated in many ways depending on the context. In a certain context it could even mean "extraordinary sexual prowess" However, ordinarily, it means the ability to do things or an achievement above the normal. Having said that, in my opinion, translating it as "forerunner" is not appropriate. If "runner" is to be retained, then perhaps "front-runner" is better in keeping with the competitive ideals of the Olympics.

Comment: I'd suggest comparing Google Translate shorter phrases then compare with the full sentence and where it doesn't make sense, either ask us back here, (try to chunk them, like 3-4 at a time, as not to clog up the board), or try /r/chineselanguage on reddit or even /r/translator

Comment: Thanks all! So it sounds like its: 有 (have) 梦 想 (dreams) 谁 都 (anyone) 了 不 起 (still don't understand, but something like "no limits"? "Bu" is in there, so it has to be negative, right?)

Comment: Quote:- ""Bu" is in there, so it has to be negative, right?"  No. The "Bu" does not stand alone. It is, perhaps for want of a better term, a "reverse negative"? Like in English you have "There is no comparison" The negative "no" here acts like the "Bu" So, 了 不 起, (which is difficult to translate literally into English), has been translated as "amazing", "terrific", "great",  "extraordinary", etc, all of which only translate the meaning. However, "no limits", (无限, Wúxiàn), may be not so accurate. 了 不 起 is more like "beyond the normal / ordinary"

Comment: Come to think of it, "There is no comparison" is, in my view, not too far from  了 不 起

Answer (score 0):

This song use many metaphors, it is not easy for language beginner.